# SSIS .dtsx package error - Failed to start project

Tags: ssis

All, I'm using visual studio community 2019 - please see error message below.  This error occurs when I try to run/execute a .dtsx package.  I've registered regsvr32 dts.dll successfully, but to no avail:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I haven't seen an error like this, I would try a reinstall of the SSIS extension

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz:  Thanks.  What I ended up doing was creating another new solution and project, then importing my .dtsx packages one by one into this new environment.  They seem to be working Ok.